# Factory method bean inheritance in Spring XML configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, inheritance, javabeans

I read, that in XML-based Spring configuration beans can inherit factory method.
I tried to implement it:
Controller interface:

```
public interface Controller {
    String method();
}
```

ControllerFactory class:

```
public class ControllerFactory {
    public Controller getController(String controllerName){
        switch(controllerName){
            case "OtherController":
                return new OtherController();
            case "SampleController":
                return new SampleController();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong controller name.");
        }
    }
}
```

SampleController implementation:

```
public class SampleController implements Controller {
    @Override
    public String method() {
        return "SampleController";
    }
}
```

OtherController implementation:

```
public class OtherController implements Controller {
    @Override
    public String method() {
        return "OtherController";
    }
}
```

But the following XML configuration:

```
<!--factory method inheritance -->
<bean id="controllerFactory" class="factory.ControllerFactory"/>
<bean id="parentController" abstract="true" factory-bean="controllerFactory" factory-method="getController"/>
<bean id="otherController" parent="parentController">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="OtherController"/>
</bean>
```

Gives compile-time error:

```
No matching constructor found in class 'Controller'
```

How can I change it to have factory method bean inheritance implemented properly?

Copying factory-method configuration to child bean works as expected:

```
<bean id="otherController" parent="parentController" factory-bean="controllerFactory" factory-method="getController">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="OtherController"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change bean with id `parentController` as follows:

`<bean id="parentController" class="factory.ControllerFactory" factory-bean="controllerFactory" factory-method="getController">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="OtherController"/>
</bean>`.

Try this it may work.

Comment: Pass constructor-arg also.